# npm installs package globally even after npm init

Tags: npm, package

I'm trying to install a npm package on a node project, but whatever I do, the module keeps installing globally.

My current dir is `D:\wrkfldr\NodeTemp` and it contains `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "nodetemp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

If I run `npm install websocket`, `package.json` remains unchanged, and the module is installed globally in `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

I have the following message when installing a package :

```
PS D:\wrkfldr\NodeTemp> npm install websocket

> websocket@1.0.28 install C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\websocket
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\websocket>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
+ websocket@1.0.28
added 7 packages from 15 contributors in 5.812s
```

I'm working under windows and I have just deleted / reinstalled node, but it didn't fix the problem.

**How can I get the packages to install locally ?**

NB: if I manually add the dependency in `package.json` and then run `npm install` it works properly, the directory node_modules is created, and my imports work as expected.

Here is my output of `npm-config ls -l`

```
; cli configs
long = true
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.4.1 node/v10.15.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\Me\.npmrc
global = true

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; default values
access = null
allow-same-version = false
also = null
always-auth = false
audit = true
audit-level = "low"
auth-type = "legacy"
bin-links = true
browser = null
ca = null
cache = "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache"
cache-lock-retries = 10
cache-lock-stale = 60000
cache-lock-wait = 10000
cache-max = null
cache-min = 10
cafile = undefined
cert = null
cidr = null
color = true
commit-hooks = true
depth = null
description = true
dev = false
dry-run = false
editor = "notepad.exe"
engine-strict = false
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
force = false
git = "git"
git-tag-version = true
; global = false (overridden)
global-style = false
globalconfig = "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\etc\\npmrc"
globalignorefile = "C:\\Users\\Me\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\etc\\npmignore"
group = 0
ham-it-up = false
heading = "npm"
https-proxy = null
if-present = false
ignore-prepublish = false
ignore-scripts = false
init-author-email = ""
init-author-name = ""
init-author-url = ""
init-license = "ISC"
init-module = "C:\\Users\\Me\\.npm-init.js"
init-version = "1.0.0"
json = false
key = null
legacy-bundling = false
link = false
local-address = undefined
loglevel = "notice"
logs-max = 10
; long = false (overridden)
maxsockets = 50
message = "%s"
; metrics-registry = null (overridden)
node-options = null
node-version = "10.15.0"
noproxy = null
offline = false
onload-script = null
only = null
optional = true
otp = null
package-lock = true
package-lock-only = false
parseable = false
prefer-offline = false
prefer-online = false
; prefix = "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs" (overridden)
preid = ""
production = false
progress = true
proxy = null
read-only = false
rebuild-bundle = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
rollback = true
save = true
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-exact = false
save-optional = false
save-prefix = "^"
save-prod = false
scope = ""
script-shell = null
scripts-prepend-node-path = "warn-only"
searchexclude = null
searchlimit = 20
searchopts = ""
searchstaleness = 900
send-metrics = false
shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe"
shrinkwrap = true
sign-git-commit = false
sign-git-tag = false
sso-poll-frequency = 500
sso-type = "oauth"
strict-ssl = true
tag = "latest"
tag-version-prefix = "v"
timing = false
tmp = "C:\\Users\\LEROIA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp"
umask = 0
unicode = false
unsafe-perm = true
update-notifier = true
usage = false
user = 0
; user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}" (overridden)
userconfig = "C:\\Users\\Me\\.npmrc"
version = false
versions = false
viewer = "browser"
```

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: node : v10.15.0, npm : 6.4.1

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when issuing the command in dos rather than powershell?

Comment: Yes, the exact same thing happens

Comment: Where is node and npm installed?

Comment: They both seems to be installed in `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: To know for sure use ```get-command npm``` in powershell or ```where npm``` in dos

Comment: They yielded the expected location : `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: What is the output of the value `global` when you run the command `npm config ls -l` ?

Comment: @axm__ updated in the question, since the paste is too big

Comment: is that the raw paste or did you edit the line with `; global = false (overridden)`?

Comment: I did not edit anything, that is a raw paste

Comment: Can you install packages to the local `node_modules` if you add `--save` like `npm install --save some-package-name`. Could you try that out? Cause I got a feeling your defaults are off (i'll come back to that after you can confirm if `--save` makes a difference)

Comment: I already tried, but just tried again right now, `--save` does not make a difference :/

Answer (score 0):

Your default for installing packages is overriden. When you run the command `npm config ls -l`, you can spot overridden values by their format: `; key = default_value (overridden)`. The overridden values are also at the top of the output when you run above-mentioned command. It will show something like:

```
; cli configs
    (...)

; userconfig C:\Users\Me\.npmrc
    global = true ---> here you can see it is overridden

; globalconfig /path/to/global/config/file
    (...) ----> if you got globally overridden default values, you see those values here


; default values
    (...)
; global = false (overridden) --> here you can see what the default value is
    (...)
```

In your case, the value for [`global`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#global) is overridden in `C:\Users\Me\.npmrc` (change it to the real path if you anonimized it). Open that file and delete the `global = true` line. You can also use the [`npm-config`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config.html) CLI, but my experience is that that doesn't always work.

After you deleted that line, run `npm config ls -l` again to verify if the config returned to the default value.